# merge query based on when not matched by target oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to do a merge query on a table or rather subset of table which matches certain condition. So exactly what I am looking for is something like below -

```
merge into table1 as target using table2 as Source on target.col1 = Source.col1
when matched then update
when not matched by target -- row exists in source but not in targer
then insert ;
```

I understand `when not matched by target` is not supported in oracle. I am wondering if there are alternatives to do the same thing in a single merge statement.Basically I want to insert only when row exists in source table and not in target table.

Comment: I failed to see why you need `by target`. Doesn't it make the job without it as `when not matched then insert ...` ?

Comment: That's exactly how `merge` statement works. There is no need for `by target` alternatives.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL here, unless you are asking for a procedural solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `BY TARGET` can just be removed for Oracle and it works as you’d expect. Here a little script with two tables that show this behaviour and that it works. You want to merge all rows from `temp_test` into `summary` that are in `temp_test` but not yet `summary`.

```
create table temp_test 
(
    DT      date,
    Foobar  varchar2(100),
    Step    varchar2(100)
);

create table summary 
(
    DT          date,
    Foobar      varchar2(100),
    Step        varchar2(100),
    OtherFields varchar2(100) NULL
);
/

insert into temp_test values (trunc(sysdate), 'test', '20'); -- should be inserted
insert into temp_test values (trunc(sysdate-1), 'test', '20'); -- already in summary

INSERT into summary (DT, Foobar, Step) VALUES (trunc(sysdate-1), 'test', '20');
select * from temp_test; -- 2 records
select * from summary; -- 1 record


merge into summary TARGET
USING temp_test SOURCE
ON (TARGET.DT = SOURCE.DT and TARGET.Foobar = SOURCE.Foobar and TARGET.Step = SOURCE.Step)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (DT, Foobar, Step) VALUES (SOURCE.DT, SOURCE.Foobar, SOURCE.Step);
-- 1 row updated

select* from gui_po_summary; -- 2 rows

-- try to merge again, nothing should be done
merge into summary TARGET
USING temp_test SOURCE
ON (TARGET.DT = SOURCE.DT and TARGET.Foobar = SOURCE.Foobar and TARGET.Step = SOURCE.Step)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (DT, Foobar, Step) VALUES (SOURCE.DT, SOURCE.Foobar, SOURCE.Step);
-- 0 rows

delete temp_test; -- 2 rows deleted
-- try to merge again, nothing should be done as we want WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target
merge into summary TARGET
USING temp_test SOURCE
ON (TARGET.DT = SOURCE.DT and TARGET.Foobar = SOURCE.Foobar and TARGET.Step = SOURCE.Step)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (DT, Foobar, Step) VALUES (SOURCE.DT, SOURCE.Foobar, SOURCE.Step);
-- 0 rows
```

There is also `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source` which needs special handling for Oracle and is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842932/4040068.